# Questions relating to shakti peetha--matabajreshwari temple in Kangra

Tags: temple, shakti, pilgrimage

1. There are some legends that there is a mysterious rock which would radiate lights during nights in old Kangra town, I wonder if this shakti pitha was located on a huge rock?
2. According to some legends, there is also a sacred spring water in the north of  the old kangra town, I guess the sacred spring water may be the one in the temple(the name of the kund maybe "havan kund" ). so has any friend here ever heard of the rock in old kangra town and is the kund in the temple a natural spring or artificial pond(no means to offend, sorry if I state improperly regarding to this kund)
3. May any friend tell me other sacred ponds(kunds) that are natural spring water near the temple?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.